# Ввод и обработка данных в разных потоках

Tags: многопоточность, разработка-игр, синхронизация

Имеется игра. В игре есть два потока - один отвечает за выполнение игрового цикла, второй поток - за ввод данных с клавиатуры и мыши. Чтобы получать данные из второго потока - необходимо подписаться на рассылку событий ввода. Обработчики событий естественно будут выполняться в потоке отвечающем за ввод данных.

**Задача:** Необходимо обрабатывать в потоке логики данные полученные из потока ввода.

**В чем проблема:**

*Во первых* - напрямую изменять логику из обработчиков ввода (т.е. из потока ввода) - нельзя. Необходима синхронизация. Данные из потока ввода используются из очень многих мест в коде логики, а это значит - код будет пестрить sybchronized секциями и методами, чего хотелось бы избежать.

*Во вторых* - в момент выполнения очередного шага игрового цикла должны обрабатываться только те события клавиатуры и мыши, которые были получены ДО начала выполнения этого шага. При этом нужно запоминать другие поступающие события с клавиатуры и мыши, но учесть их только во время следующего шага цикла.

*В третьих* - иногда на событие нажатия кнопки следует выполнение очень длинного по времени метода, т.е. в момент вызова этого метода поток ввода "застрянет", а так как у меня поток ввода это и  GUI поток - то это в двойне нежелательно.

**Как я пытался решить проблему:** Я создал класс являющийся буффером ввода, т.е. класс запоминает все события поступившие с клавиатуры и мыши, сохраняя их в специальном буффере. В начале шага игрового цикла - данные из буффера переносятся в рабочее хранилище, от куда их будет считывать поток логики, а поток ввода может снова делать запись в буффер. Получается - синхронизация нужна только в момент переноса данных из буффера в хранилище(я просто меняю местами хранилище и буффер).

**Вопрос:** Адекватен ли способ которым я пытался решить проблему? Есть ли способ лучше?

Comment: Спасибо, Mike. Я написал - "копировать буффер в хранилище" чтобы прояснить что я делаю. Фактически у меня есть два одинаковых массива событий - хранилище и буффер. В момент синхронизации я меняю местами ссылки на них и отпускаю блокировку. Думаю это быстро.

Comment: Проблема в другом - в буффере хранится информация не только мыши и клавиатуре, но и о том - на какую кнопку интерфейса нажал игрок и т.д. Тут нельзя допускать состояние гонки. По этому при каждом добавлении события поток ввода захватывает монитор. И вот как эту проблему решить я не знаю.

Comment: Как раз на случай переключения указателя буффера.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90839/discussion-between-bakuard-and-mike).

Comment: Перенес все соображения в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал [кольцевой буфер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80) достаточного размера (с запасом). Поток обработки клавиатуры пишет в него, двигая указатель на голову. Поток игрового цикла в момент начала цикла запоминает текущий указатель на голову  и далее спокойно обрабатывает события из того же самого буфера, читая их по очереди по указателю хвоста. Когда хвост достигает запомненного указателя головы - значит данные закончились.

В данном случае есть две точки, при которых теоретически могла бы понадобиться синхронизация потоков:

- Сохранение текущего указателя головы, в потоке игрового цикла. Да, имеет место доступ к переменной, изменяемой в другом потоке. Но эта переменная в том потоке монотонно увеличивается, изредка сбрасываясь на начало. Нас вполне устроит любое из ее значений, которое могло образоваться в момент копирования. Значит нам достаточно убедится что переменная была атомарно прочитана. Если указатель это обычный int то ни один нормальный компилятор не сгенерит код, который бы читал его частями.
- Проверка в потоке чтения клавиатуры, что голова не подошла к хвосту с другой стороны. Т.е. проверка на переполнение буфера. Если такая ситуация возникает, то в любом случае у нас начнутся серьезные проблемы, нам придется начать выбрасывать не обработанные события. Она может возникнуть либо при слишком малом размере буфера, либо при зависании игрового (читающего события) потока. Для такой проверки более чем достаточно не синхронизированного значения хвоста. Даже если читающий поток на момент возникновения события уже почти подвинул хвост, т.е. освободил один элемент, а мы этого не заметим, погоды это не сделает, буфер все равно на грани переполнения.

Таким образом можно вполне обойтись вообще без каких либо блокировок потоков при работе с кольцевым буфером событий.